# TabHost android isn't working correctly

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I am trying to get this TabHost to work. When I add the TabHost to the xml layout and run the program I can see the different content for each tab stacked on top of each other.  This tells me that the layout is working properly.  I then add my spec code to the activity and then if closes the program on the emulator when I navigate to this screen.
So here is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tWelcome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bNewTask"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Task" />

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/myTabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tTest"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Test"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
 </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here now is my Activity code: (The only part that matters...)

```
            welcomeName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tWelcome);
    Test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tTest);
    newTask = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNewTask);
    myTask = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    TabHost th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.myTabs);

    welcomeName.setText("Welcome " + ToDoActivity.myUser.getName() + "!");

    th.setup();
    TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    specs.setIndicator("All");
    th.addTab(specs);
    specs = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    specs.setIndicator("Personal");
    th.addTab(specs);
```

Comment: why not you use `TabLayout` instead of `TabHost`?

Answer (score 0):

A couple possibilities come to mind.

If you're using a TabActivity (not a requirement, but makes things easier), the tabhost must have `android:id="@android:id/tabhost"` as the id.

I've also seen it said that the tabhost must be the root node.  I cannot confirm that using the android docs.  I'd probably make this change after all other avenues have failed (or someone confirms that it is true).

If you are using a TabActivity, you don't need to reference the tabhost by id, or use the setup() method.  I see you are using the setup() method, but I can;t tell if your activity is a TabActivity.  If it is, maybe that's causing your issue.

Following is the method I use for a tab layout setup and it works for me.  Note that this assumes the tabhost as the root node of the layout and it has `android:id/tabhost` as the id and it is a TabActivity.

**tabhost code:**

```
public class Tabs extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;

        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag1").setIndicator("All").setContent(R.id.tab1);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag2").setIndicator("Personal").setContent(R.id.tab2);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!  (Be sure to click the check mark to accept the answer if it solves your problem).

Comment: The getTabHost() isn't a method I have defined.  Do I make this method return the TabHost Id or something?

Comment: If you are extending TabActivity it is a method from there.

Comment: Please keep in mind that TabActivity is deprecated. I would use ActionBarSherlock http://actionbarsherlock.com/ and use only the new ActionBar APIs to create Tabs. This makes everything a lot easier especially moving to Ice Cream Sandwich, that will get a lot of new devices in the next half year...

Comment: Modified my answer to be a bit clearer.  Check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) for more info about methods available by extending the TabActivity class.  Although it should be noted they have deprecated it in favor of using fragments.  I haven't made that move yet so I cannot be of much help if you desire to do it that way.

Comment: Will I be able to extend TabActivity and still have all my other functions work that aren't in the TabHost?

Comment: I don't know since I don't know your code, but TabActivity is an extension of Activity, so if that's what you were using before I would think it should continue to work.

Comment: ok I tried it and it still closed the program when I navigate to this page.  Like I said before, if I comment out the Activity code i posted above the code works and I can see each tab layered above each other.  So I commented this out and tried to extend TabActivity and it didn't even work then.  So does this mean that TabActivity won't work for me?

Comment: post your logcat so we can see whats happening

Comment: 03-30 15:44:43.850: W/ThrottleService(88): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0

Answer (score 0):

This is the Android tutorial page for tabs:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

It has information and requirements about Tabs and it gives lots of sample code. You should be able to copy-paste from there and then edit.

Specifically, I'd change the ids for all the Tab elements to be the suggested Android ids:

```
android:id/tabhost
android:id/tabs
android:id/tabcontent
```